# Firefox unable to display anything despite a complete purge and reinstall

Tags: firefox

My firefox has been completely broken since two days. A complete purge and reinstall as well as erasing every firefox folder has not helped.

Firefox is unable to load or display pages. Even about:config or preferences. I just get a blank screen, even under safemode and after a fresh reinstall.

Other browsers and applications seem to work fine.

See screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: How about switching to default theme? Or, open Web Developer --> Network or Browser Console to confirm if no activity or just a display issue?

Comment: You could also try booting from an Ubuntu Live CD (which includes Firefox)? I suspect that will work, but you can test some of your custom settings to see if something goes wrong.